# how to include apoc.* procedure and functions in the Neo4J embedded server

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, jqassistant, apoc

I am using jqassistant to create a graph of the microservices on my project. However, seems to have hit a wall. JqAssistant uses an embedded server of Neo4j. This server does not include "apoc" functions and procedures. How Can i install these on the embedded server.

**I have tried:**

1. Copied all the required apoc jars mainly: apoc-all, apoc-core, apoc-extended jars in the lib
2. Added these jar to the classpath
3. Server runs fine but APOC procs are still not available.

Seems like I need to change the **dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*** property, In desktop or server installation this is found in neo4j.conf file in the neo4j configuration directory. However, JqAssistant uses an embedded server cant seems to locate this file.

Answer (score 0):

With the upcoming jQAssistant release 2.1.0 there will be improved support for registering Neo4j plugins providing functions/procedures. You can grab 2.1.0-RC1 which has been released last week and add the following entry to your .jqassistant.yml:

Neo4j v4:

```
jqassistant:
  store:
    embedded:
      neo4j-plugins:
        - group-id: org.neo4j.procedure
          artifact-id: apoc
          version: 4.4.0.25
```

Neo4j v5:

```
jqassistant:
  store:
    embedded:
      neo4j-plugins:
        - group-id: org.neo4j.procedure
          artifact-id: apoc-core
          classifier: core
          version: 5.17.1
```